# Mongoose Populate in Node JS

Tags: schema, mongoose, populate

I've been trying to follow the information in [Mongoose Population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html), but I'm getting the exception:

**MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "undefined".**

The code I have goes like this:

```js
mongoose = require('mongoose');
Schema = mongoose.Schema;
mongoose.connect(MONGO_SERVER);
ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var FirstSchema = new Schema({
    label       : String
});
var SecondSchema = new Schema({
    first_id           : [{ type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'First' }],
    type           : String,
    // ...
});
var first= mongoose.model('First', FirstSchema);
var second= mongoose.model('Second', SecondSchema);

function test() {
    // ...
    second.find({}).populate('first_id').exec(function(err,data){return true;});
    // ...
}
```

And the error occurs on the populate, I've tweaked it a number of times to different answers found on forums, and I'm sure it will be something simple, but can someone point me in the right direction?

Cheers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your schema definitions, I see that you have defined 'first_id' as an array in Second schema. Compared to a relational database, this will be like an one-to-many relationship in which the parent table is the Second collection, and First collection as the child. Then you're doing wrong trying to populate the second with the first.

Suppose I have a Users collection, and a Clients collection, in which each client has an user related to it. Then the code will be:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://userName:password@server:port/dbname');
var conn = mongoose.connection;
conn.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
conn.once('open', function callback () {
    console.log('connected ');
});

var user = mongoose.Schema({
    userName: String
});

var client = mongoose.Schema({
    fk_user: { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Users' },
    name: String
});

var UserModel = mongoose.model('Users', user);
var ClientModel = mongoose.model('Clients', client);

ClientModel.findOne().populate('fk_user').exec(function(err, c) {
    if (err) { return console.log(err); }

    console.log(c.fk_user.userName);
});
```

Hope this give you some point to help.

Comment: Many thanks, John!  I must have copied in that part to make that ref field object in to an array from somewhere, or it was a typo, anyway - it's all fixed now, Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error

Schema hadn't been registered for model "States".

Sometimes it might also be that the model you are trying to reference is not assigned to a schema.

like in the code below.

First: I was trying to reference the `states` model I created with `States`, but it was not the name of the model. Instead, the name was `states`

```js
const CountriesSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type:String,required:true },
    capital: { type:String },
    description: { type:String },
    cord: {
        latitude: { type:Number },
        longitude: { type:Number }
    },
    state: [{ type:Schema.Types.ObjectId , ref:'States' }],
    date_created: { type:Date },
    date_modeified: { type:Date }
});
```

Meanwhile the real name of the model was states

```js
const State = mongoose.model( 'states', StateSchema ); // <= Typo here
module.exports = State ;
```

All I need to do was change the `States` to `states`:

```js
var CountriesSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type:String,required:true },
    capital: { type:String },
    description: { type:String },
    cord: {
        latitude: { type:Number },
        longitude: { type:Number }
    },
    state: [{ type:Schema.Types.ObjectId , ref:'states' }],
    date_created: { type:Date },
    date_modeified: { type:Date }
});
```